# Getting "Can't pickle local object" error in Flask & Web Socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, flask, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multi-processing and socket_io to run some asynchronous processes in a form of flask api

this is my code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

csv_data = []

#turn the flask app into a socketio app
socket_io = SocketIO(app, async_mode=None, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()


@app.route('/face_reognition/multi_core', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def face_recognition_multi_core():
    try:
        start = time.time()
        if request.method == "POST":

            stream_links = request.form['stream_links']
            location = request.form['location']
            camera = request.form['camera']
            FREQUENCY = request.form['frequency']
            TOLERANCE_THRES = request.form['tolerance_threshold']
            count = 0
            FREQUENCY = int(FREQUENCY) or FREQUENCY == 10
            TOLERANCE_THRES = float(TOLERANCE_THRES) or TOLERANCE_THRES == 0.45
            hogFaceDetector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

            with open('faces_encodings.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
                faces_encodings = pickle.load(handle)

            def one_to_one(stream_link, count):
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_link)

                if not cap.isOpened():
                    print("Error opening video stream or file")

                while cap.isOpened():

                    count = count + 1

                    ret, frame = cap.read()

                    if ret:
                        frame = resize_img(frame, 50)
                        if count % FREQUENCY == 0:
                            face_locations = hogFaceDetector(frame, 0)

                            if len(face_locations) > 0:
                                sorted_detections_distances = calculate_face_distance(face_locations, frame,
                                                                                      faces_encodings)

                                if sorted_detections_distances[0][1] < TOLERANCE_THRES:
                                    now = datetime.now()  # current date and time
                                    found_date = now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

                                    result = {
                                        "Location": stream_link,
                                        "worker_name": sorted_detections_distances[0][0],
                                        "time": found_date
                                    }

                                    csv_data.append(result)

                                    # keys = result.keys()
                                    with open('multi_core.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
                                        pickle.dump(csv_data, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                                        handle.close()
                                        with open('multi_core.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
                                            latest_data = pickle.load(handle)[-1]
                                            print(latest_data)
                                            socket_io.emit('my_response', {"data": dict(latest_data)})



                        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                            break
                    else:
                        break

                cap.release()

                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                for stream_link in stream_links:
                    executor.submit(one_to_one,stream_link, count)

            end = time.time() - start

            print(end)

        return render_template("index.html")

    except Exception as e:

        return e
```

when I am testing POST api on **http://0.0.0.0:5000/face_reognition/multi_core** it is giving this error

> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'face_recognition_multi_core..one_to_one'

But when I was running this on synchronous function based it was working

this is working  **synchronous** code:

```
@app.route('/face_reognition/single_core', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def face_recognition():
    try:
        start = time.time()
        if request.method == "POST":

            stream_link = request.form['stream_link']
            location = request.form['location']
            camera = request.form['camera']
            FREQUENCY = request.form['frequency']
            TOLERANCE_THRES = request.form['tolerance_threshold']
            count = 0
            FREQUENCY = int(FREQUENCY) or FREQUENCY == 10
            TOLERANCE_THRES = float(TOLERANCE_THRES) or TOLERANCE_THRES == 0.45
            hogFaceDetector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_link)

            if not cap.isOpened():
                return ("Error opening video stream")

            with open('faces_encodings.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
                faces_encodings = pickle.load(handle)

            while cap.isOpened():

                count = count + 1

                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if ret:
                    frame = resize_img(frame, 50)
                    if count % FREQUENCY == 0:
                        face_locations = hogFaceDetector(frame, 0)

                        if len(face_locations) > 0:
                            sorted_detections_distances = calculate_face_distance(face_locations, frame,
                                                                                  faces_encodings)

                            if sorted_detections_distances[0][1] < TOLERANCE_THRES:
                                # return {"face_id":TOLERANCE_THRES}

                                now = datetime.now()  # current date and time
                                found_date = now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

                                result = {
                                    "Location": stream_link,
                                    "worker_name": sorted_detections_distances[0][0],
                                    "time": found_date
                                }

                                csv_data.append(result)

                                # keys = result.keys()
                                with open('main_data_new.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
                                    pickle.dump(csv_data, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                                    handle.close()
                                    with open('main_data_new.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
                                        latest_data = pickle.load(handle)[-1]
                                        print(latest_data)
                                        socket_io.emit('my_response', {"data":dict(latest_data)})


                    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break
                else:
                    break


            cap.release()

            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

            end = time.time() - start

            print(end)

        return render_template("index.html")

    except Exception as e:

        return  e
```